# Django: Creating model managers does not work

Tags: django, python-3.x

Please help me ... I understand that the problem is very simple ... but I'm stuck!
I Creating model managers

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                 self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    ...................
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
```

and this is what I get in the terminal

```
 >>> Post.objects.filter(publish__year=2020, author__username='sasa')
     <QuerySet [<Post: try>, <Post: 3 article>]>
 >>> Post.published.filter(publish__year=2020, author__username='sasa')
     <QuerySet []>
 >>>
```

Post.object.filter... works correctly, but    Post.published.filter    returns an empty object 
 This is not right? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Well are there `published` `Post`s in the year `2020` with username `sasa`? Can you please share more details of your `Post` model?

Comment: Wow.. So, it works with published data .... Thanks! You really helped me! Everything works!